# How to group and sum values in array of arrays with the same structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this array of arrays in the data attribute for each activity corresponding to the class attendance by hour.

I need the total attendance of each activity by hour.
Is it possible to group and sum it?

Example:
The correct result for the hour 7 is 50+60 = 110

```
[{:name=>"cardio", 
:data=>[["06", 999], ["07", 50], ["08", 0], ["09", 154], ["10", 1059], ["11", 90], ["12", 30], ["13", 0], ["14", 0], ["15", 0], ["16", 0], ["17", 0], ["18", 0], ["19", 0], ["20", 0], ["21", 0], ["22", 0], ["23", 0]]}, 
:name=>"swimming", 
:data=>[["06", 0], ["07", 60], ["08", 0], ["09", 0], ["10", 90], ["11", 50], ["12", 0], ["13", 0], ["14", 0], ["15", 0], ["16", 0], ["17", 0], ["18", 0], ["19", 0], ["20", 0], ["21", 0], ["22", 0], ["23", 0]]}]
```

Expected result:

```
:data=>[["06", 999], ["07", 110], ["08", 0], ["09", 154], ["10", 1149], ["11", 140], ["12", 30], ["13", 0], ["14", 0], ["15", 0], ["16", 0], ["17", 0], ["18", 0], ["19", 0], ["20", 0], ["21", 0], ["22", 0], ["23", 0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Case 1: The values of `:data` are arrays of the same size whose elements (two-element arrays) are ordered the same by their first elements**

```
arr = [{ :name=>"cardio",   :data=>[["06", 999], ["07", 50], ["08", 0]] }, 
       { :name=>"swimming", :data=>[["06",   0], ["07", 60], ["08", 0]] }]

a, b = arr.map { |h| h[:data].transpose }.transpose
  #=> [[["06", "07", "08"], ["06", "07", "08"]], [[999, 50, 0], [0, 60, 0]]]
{ :data=>a.first.zip(b.transpose.map { |col| col.reduce(:+) }) }
  #=> {:data=>[["06", 999], ["07", 110], ["08", 0]]}
```

**Case 2: The values of `:data` are arrays which may differ in size and whose elements (two-element arrays) may not be ordered the same by their first element**

```
arr = [{ :name=>"cardio",   :data=>[["05", 999], ["07", 50], ["08",  0]] }, 
       { :name=>"swimming", :data=>[["08", 300], ["04", 33], ["07", 60]] }] 

{ :data=>arr.flat_map { |g| g[:data] }.
    each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(f,v),h| h[f] += v }.
    sort.
    to_a }
  #=>  {:data=>[["04", 33], ["05", 999], ["07", 110], ["08", 300]]}
```

Note:

- depending on requirements, `sort` may not be required
- the second method could be used regardless of whether the values of `:data` are defined in parallel
- the second method uses the form of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) which takes an argument (the *default value*) which here is zero. This is sometimes called a *counting hash*. See the doc for details.

Comment: Interesting! I've never thought of using `Array#transpose` this way.

Answer (score 2):

> How to group and sum values in array of arrays with the same structure

You should do it like this :

```
[{:name=>"cardio", 
:data=>[["06", 999], ["07", 50], ["08", 0], ["09", 154], ["10", 1059], ["11", 90], ["12", 30], ["13", 0], ["14", 0], ["15", 0], ["16", 0], ["17", 0], ["18", 0], ["19", 0], ["20", 0], ["21", 0], ["22", 0], ["23", 0]]}, 
:name=>"swimming", 
:data=>[["06", 0], ["07", 60], ["08", 0], ["09", 0], ["10", 90], ["11", 50], ["12", 0], ["13", 0], ["14", 0], ["15", 0], ["16", 0], ["17", 0], ["18", 0], ["19", 0], ["20", 0], ["21", 0], ["22", 0], ["23", 0]]}]
```

Try this one:

```
act.map{|h| h[:data]}.flatten(1).group_by(&:first).map { |k,v| [k, v.map(&:last).inject(:+)] }
# => [["06", 999], ["07", 110], ["08", 0], ["09", 154], ["10", 1149], ["11", 140], ["12", 30], ["13", 0], ["14", 0], ["15", 0], ["16", 0], ["17", 0], ["18", 0], ["19", 0], ["20", 0], ["21", 0], ["22", 0], ["23", 0]]
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
act=[{:name=>"cardio", 
:data=>[["06", 999], ["07", 50], ["08", 0], ["09", 154], ["10", 1059], ["11", 90], ["12", 30], ["13", 0], ["14", 0], ["15", 0], ["16", 0], ["17", 0], ["18", 0], ["19", 0], ["20", 0], ["21", 0], ["22", 0], ["23", 0]]}, 
{:name=>"swimming", 
:data=>[["06", 0], ["07", 60], ["08", 0], ["09", 0], ["10", 90], ["11", 50], ["12", 0], ["13", 0], ["14", 0], ["15", 0], ["16", 0], ["17", 0], ["18", 0], ["19", 0], ["20", 0], ["21", 0], ["22", 0], ["23", 0]]}]
```

You can do:

```
> act.map{ |h| h[:data] }
       .flatten(1)
       .group_by{ |h,n| h }
       .map { |k,v| [k, v.map(&:last).sum] }
=> [["06", 999], ["07", 110], ["08", 0], ["09", 154], ["10", 1149], ["11", 140], ["12", 30], ["13", 0], ["14", 0], ["15", 0], ["16", 0], ["17", 0], ["18", 0], ["19", 0], ["20", 0], ["21", 0], ["22", 0], ["23", 0]]
```

Or,

```
> act.map{|h| h[:data]}
     .flatten(1)
     .each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|e,h| h[e[0]]+=e[1]}.to_a
```

works too.

Answer (score 0):

```
actions=[{:name=>"cardio", 
:data=>[["06", 999], ["07", 50], ["08", 0], ["09", 154], ["10", 1059], ["11", 90], ["12", 30], ["13", 0], ["14", 0], ["15", 0], ["16", 0], ["17", 0], ["18", 0], ["19", 0], ["20", 0], ["21", 0], ["22", 0], ["23", 0]]}, 
{:name=>"swimming", 
:data=>[["06", 0], ["07", 60], ["08", 0], ["09", 0], ["10", 90], ["11", 50], ["12", 0], ["13", 0], ["14", 0], ["15", 0], ["16", 0], ["17", 0], ["18", 0], ["19", 0], ["20", 0], ["21", 0], ["22", 0], ["23", 0]]}]

actions.map{|act| act[:data]}.reduce({}) do |acc, data|
  acc.merge(data.to_h) {|k, v1, v2| v1 + v2}
end.to_a
```

This solution takes advantage of the fact that Ruby's `Hash` keeps the insertion order.

The merit of this algorithm is that it allows missing keys in either data array.